# Hosting a WCF Service

Tags: wcf, hosting, wcf-hosting

So i am new to WCF Services and I need to create a dulplex service (working on it) however I cannot figure out where/how to host it (external). Right now I am using http://aspspider.com for my hosting, which works fine, but i am having trouble geting a wcf service application working.

I found this example which i will be using to help get my service working. I tried to just upload the service to aspspider, but i get an error.

---

Configuration Error  Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

```
Line 29: ASP.NET to identify an incoming user.   
Line 30:  -->  
>>>Line 31: <authentication mode="Windows"/>  
Line 32: <!--  
Line 33: <customErrors> section enables configuration
```

---

The service works fine locally, so i just need help to get it working on aspspider (or if you have a better option).

Comment: Fixed, file structure was incorrect. It works fine now. Couldnt answer my own question because of rep.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question, then (after the minimum time span has passed) you can mark your answer as the accepted answer. This is also good to keep your acceptance rating up, but (more importantly) allows future visits to immediately see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Station5.net](http://station5.net) as my host and never had any issues with them.